#sharp timeout exception .net8
We're using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib in C# to make an snmp request, when we used .net 4.6.2 the request executed successfully, when we updated to .net8 we keep getting a timeout exception regardless of how long we set the timeout to, it fails at the reply
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Security;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace SNMP
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public static string GetSNMP(string username, string authPassword, string privacyPassword, string ipAddress, string snmpId)
    {
      var auth = new SHA1AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString(authPassword));
      var priv = new DESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString(privacyPassword), auth);

      Discovery discovery = Messenger.GetNextDiscovery(SnmpType.GetNextRequestPdu);

      ReportMessage report = discovery.GetResponse(60000, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), 161));

      GetRequestMessage request = new GetRequestMessage(VersionCode.V3, Messenger.NextMessageId, Messenger.NextRequestId, new OctetString(username), new List<Variable> {
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(snmpId))
      }, priv, Messenger.MaxMessageSize, report);

      ISnmpMessage reply = request.GetResponse(60000, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), 161));

      if (reply.Pdu().ErrorStatus.ToInt32() != 0) // != ErrorCode.NoError   
      {
        throw ErrorException.Create("error in response", IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), reply);
      }
      var resultVariable = reply.Pdu().Variables[0];
      return resultVariable.Data.ToString();
    }
  }
}

I tried Isolating the code to handle just one request, I tried analyzing the SNMP Exception, Telnet to the server and pinged the server which both were successful

The connection is not completing.  The timeout is the time to get data after the connection completes.  Check the request and see if there is any errors.  I suspect the authentication is failing.  A lot has change since 4.6.2.  Does 4.6.2 still work?

SNMP in c# requires a new instance of the class for each message.  You cannot reuse the same instance with multiple messages.

https://docs.lextudio.com/sharpsnmplib/tutorials/troubleshooting#how-to-capture-network-packets Did you observe anything useful from the network packets?

@jdweng It can't be the authentication I'm using the exact same credentials that we were using in 4.6.2, we were forced to redeploy the old solution which 4.6.2 but it runs without issue,
We do create a new instance of the class, in this code snippet i've provided it only handles one request
I've tried all the .net versions from 5 to 8 to see if there would be any changes but it always gets a timeout error, and the documentation show no differences in the  implementation using the latest package

@LexLi I have used wireshark to check but haven't noticed anything that stands out, this might be to my inexperience with working from it but it didn't display anything that seemed like an error

In wire shark do you see the TLS packets?  What version of TLS?  Do you see the Https packets?  TLS is run before HTTP(s) and if TLS fails than you will not see the HTTP(s).  TLS you should only see TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Can you connect with Postman?  Compare the postman and the c#.  See if the HTTP headers are the same.  See if Postman is using the same version of TLS.

@jdweng In wireshark I filter by snmp, I see a :106 get next request, 210 encryptedPDU :privKey Unkown and a 148 report with OID

It looks like the key is unknown.   Does 4.6.2 still work on the machine?  What has changed since code last worked?  Is report failing or reply failing?  If report is working what is the status.  200 OK or a 400/500 error.

@jdweng Via postman I'm finding it a bit difficult to create an request for SNMP as its not meant for it , I'll keep trying at let you know if I see anything

see https://postman-v1.guides.gov.sg/email-api-guide/programmatic-email-api/send-email-api

@jdweng, Yeah 4.6.2 works a 100% no issues at all, nothing changed in the code we just upgraded to .net8, the reply fails with the error being a timeout exception with no inner error, well there isn't any status codes that get returned so that was also something that made it difficult

I assume same account and same machine.  Starting with Net 4.7.1 TLS is done in OS instead of in Net.  Also SSL, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 is obsolete and you can only use TLS 1.2, and 1.3.  We need to find out if TLS passed or failed using Wireshark.  TLS is performed before the HTTP request is sent so verify if the HTTP packet was sent.  HTTP will not be sent if TLS fails.  There may be something in the csproj file that is causing issue.  For example starting with 4.7.1 you can specify is TLS is done with Net or OS.  You should be using OS.

Also make sure you do a clean build so no intermediate obj file exist.  You can check the project folder obj and bin folder to make sure the dates of all the files are current.  Also check references to make sure old libraries are not being called.  Net 8 still has bugs and maybe Net 7 is better.

@jdweng Okay I'll try to figure out if tls is being done on the os or with net, but in wireshark, when I filter by the IP being used in the SNMP request there is no information linked to that IP for the tls filter, and when I filter by IP there is no information related to that IP,
I have done a clean build before trying to see if it changes anything but no luck, I will try creating a new project using Net7 to see if the project would work, we are using the latest package of #sharp for the snmp in the docs it says its compatible with .net8 but I couldn't find anything specific on the web

Do you see any TLS packets?  If you are not seeing SNMP than the TLS is failing.  It is possible the IP is going through a proxy.  Email normally on a corporate network uses Port Forwarding to forward all email port numbers to the proxy server.  IP address isn't important.  You can check the 4.6.2 with sniffer for comparison.
